# Writing to a GL_TEXTURE_3D

Tags: opengl, textures, compute-shader

I have a GL_TEXTURE_3D of size 16x16x6 and I write to it in a compute shader, however I can only seem to write to the values where `z=0`. If I attempt to call imageStore with any coordinate where `z!=0` the value doesn't appear in the texture.

What could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you have bound your 3D texture with the layered parameter set to false. Check the man page: https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glBindImageTexture.xhtml

When binding 3D textures, you have to use the layered parameter, otherwise, you can only write to one layer (most likely, layer 0.)